# How to disable triple click in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way, either built-in or by third-party extension, to disable triple-click from selecting the entire line while in a text editor? Either my mouse is too sensitive, or I'm inadvertently doing it, but more often than not, clicking a word, then copy / pasting it results in pasting of the entire line -- not my intention and very annoying. Ideally, it could be disabled (aka any click more than 1 just selects the word the cursor is over)

Comment: I think that is something built-in but on Windows, since this behaviour is reproducible outside VS. I would recommend to change the Double-Click speed on Mouse Settings in Windows to see if that makes the trick for you.

Comment: Bummer, I may try that, though I don't want to necessarily change it outside of VS, I triple-click to select a url in a browser all the time wo/issue

Comment: Is it possible that you are hitting Ctrl+C without anything selected?  VS will copy the entire line if you do this.

Comment: definitely, a possibility, I wasn't aware VS would do that

Comment: I guess one reason I am getting caught by this same issue is because the word-match hilight colour is only a slightly paler shade of blue compared to the selection colour. If there are no other matches near the word, then I mistakenly think the text is selected.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments the problem is most likely that the word highlighting color is so similar to the color of selected text. So seems like we sometimes deselect a word instead of selecting it. And without a selection  Ctrl-C copies the whole line. I had the same issue with JetBrains WebStorm. In Visual Studio for me it was ReSharper.

Changing the color helps. Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> "ReSharper Usage of element under cursor". I made that darker such that selected text is clearly distinguishable.